# Is the soft iron core inside a solenoid moved?

Tags: electromagnetism

We know that a soft iron bar placed inside a solenoid turns into an electromagnet when current passes through the solenoid. Now my question is how is electricity produced? Is the iron core moved by the turbine inside a solenoid? Because I know that a moving magnetic field creates electric field. Please help me on this.

Comment: >An electromagnet is a type of magnet in which the magnetic field is produced by an electric current. The magnetic field disappears when the current is turned off

Under the influence of external magnetic field created the solenoid, the atomic constituents of the soft iron core(which is a ferromagnetic material) undergo rearrangement which leads to it becoming a magnet.

If you are talking about the principle of the generator, changing magnetic field creates electromotive force.It is based on the principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction

Answer (score 0):

This it because it produces a changing magnetic field. And Maxwell's equations (Faraday's law) teaches us that a changing magnetic field results in an electric field, which gives rise to a current in a nearby wire. It's not the magnetic field providing the force, it's the electric field generated by the changing magnetic field. (The current disappears when you stop moving the magnet with respect to the solenoid, i.e. when the magnetic field stops changing)

With the coil stationary and the magnet moving, we have to perform a Lorentz transformation (a change in coordinates that occurs when we switch velocities, used in special relativity). Under such a transformation, a moving magnetic field becomes a stationary magnetic field plus an electric field.

In this case the magnetic field doesn't change direction, but an electric field is produced and it is this field that causes the electrons to move.

A full understanding of the dynamics of electric and magnetic fields can't work without including special relativity which is why, usually, the question of current induction is explained in terms of Faraday's Law, which is yet another perspective on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The common purpose of every modern power station is to either directly,  (an example is a  hydroelectric station) or indirectly,  for example a nuclear power creating steam, by use of a turbine system, to ultimately cause the rotation of a section of an electrical generating system.

In  induction, an electrical current passes through a wire, and a magnetic field is generated. If the magnetic field around a wire is changed by by rotating magnets attached to the rotating shaft mentioned above, inside a stationary coil or alternatively by using the rotational energy to turn a coil inside a stationary magnet, electricity will flow through the wire, and eventually to homes and industrial centres.

[image]

Image Source: [Power Stations](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/egee401/content/p6_p2.html)